# Intel's x86 manuals say JA/JNBE is taken when (CF or ZF) = 0. Is that an error?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, manual, eflags

I downloaded the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) combined volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D, and 4.

At `Table 7-4. Conditional Jump Instructions` it says the instructions `JA/JNBE` jump when `(CF or ZF) = 0`.

According to [this manual](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html), and the JCC entry in Intel's [vol.2 manual (May 2018)](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf), they jump when `(CF = 0 and ZF = 0)`, which is correct as I tested.

Is that possible Intel's developers manual to be wrong in major commands like that?

PS: I am not very sure about the instruction (I think it was JL/JNGE) but I also found  another mistake on jumping conditions

Comment: Note: It's *instruction,* not *command.*  Using wrong terms is very confusing for readers.

Comment: You realize those are the same, right? If `(CF or ZF)=0` then both must be zero. It's bitwise/boolean `or`.

Comment: @Jester Hm.... In the way you interpret it, as a bitwise  operator between them yes, you have absolutely right but I didn't interepreted this way. Instead I read it as if CF=0 or if ZF=0 (not as a bitwise act) separately.  Right now with clear head i see the role of parenthesis and I can surely say that it is a bitwise act between two operands.

Comment: @Fuz you have absolutely right, sorry for the confusion !

Comment: Intel's own volume 2 manual says `(CF = 0 and ZF = 0)`.  Which volume is table 7-4 in?  Vol 1 I assume?  I didn't check that the JCC entry in the combined manual matches the separate vol 2A/B/C PDF, but I assume that's the case.  (It's certainly possible for some parts of Intel's manuals to have errors, and it does happen, but this is not one of those cases.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Volume 1 page 184.